# How to report length of string entered by user

Tags: javascript

Ok, so here's my script...I can't get it to output the length of the string though! Please help, I'm a complete noob when it comes to Javascript, this is for a college class. Thanks!

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*
Purpose of script: report length of string given by user
*/
  "use strict";
  function stringLength()
  {
  var str=(document.StringLength.string);
  var n=str.length;
  document.StringLength.answerBox.value=length;
  }
  //Get string from user
  //Output to user
  </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<form name = StringLength>
Enter Your String <input type = "text" name = "string">
<br>
Length <input type = "text" name = "answerBox">

<input type = "button" onclick = "stringLength()" value = "Run">


  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the length of the *value* of the `string` input box

```
function stringLength(){
    var str=document.StringLength.string.value;
    var len=str.length;
    document.StringLength.answerBox.value=len;
}
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/8sCA2/) for a demo.

Comment: Yes, it is, I got my script working now, thank you! (I made a stupid typo /facepalm)

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this:

```
var x = document.getElementById('yourinput');
var y = document.getElementById('characters');
x.onkeyup = function() {
  y.innerHTML = x.value.length;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AZKyn/64/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function stringLength()
  {
  var str=(document.StringLength.string);
  var n=str.length;
  document.StringLength.answerBox.value = n ;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this one, you have not ended `form` tag properly

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*
    Purpose of script: report length of string given by user
    */

      function stringLength()
      {          
          document.StringLength.answerBox.value=document.StringLength.string.value.length;
      }
  //Get string from user
  //Output to user
  </script>
</HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <form name ="StringLength" >
            Enter Your String <input type = "text" name = "string">
            <br>        Length <input type = "text" name = "answerBox">     
            <input type = "button" onclick = "stringLength()" value = "Run">
        </form>/*encloded form tag here*/

     </BODY>
</HTML>
```